# Iterating over regions of numpy array in parallel

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have an 3D array and need to iterate over it, extract a 2x2x2 voxel large region and check if any voxel is non-zero. Of these locations, I need the unique elements of the region and the index:

```
import time
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

def _naive_iterator(array):
    lookup = np.pad(array, (1, 1), 'constant')  # Border is filled with 0
    nx, ny, nz = lookup.shape
    for i in range(nx - 1):
        for j in range(ny - 1):
            for k in range(nz - 1):
                n = lookup[i:i + 2, j:j + 2, k:k + 2]
                if n.any():  # check if any value in the region is non-zero
                    yield n.ravel(), i, j, k
                    # yield set(n.ravel()), i, j, k  # `set()` alone takes some time - for testing purposes exclude this

# arrays that shall be used here are in the region of (1000, 1000, 1000) or larger
# arrays are asserted to contain only integer values >= 0.
array = np.random.randint(0, 2, (200, 200, 200), dtype=np.uint8)

for fun in (_naive_iterator, ):
    print(f"* {fun}")
    for _ in range(2):
        tic = time.time()
        [x for x in fun(array)]
        print(f" ** execution took {time.time() - tic}")
```

On my PC, this loop takes about 24s to run. (Interesting sidenote: without the n.any(), the loop needs only 8s, so maybe there is some optimization potential as well?)

I thought about how I could make this faster, potentially by running it in parallel. But, I can not figure out how I could do that, without pre-generating all the 2x2x2 arrays.
I also thought about using [`scipy.ndimage.generic_filter`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.generic_filter.html?highlight=generic_filter#scipy.ndimage.generic_filter) but with that I can only get an image which has for example 1 on all pixels that I want to include, but I would had to iterate over the original image to get `n.ravel()` (Ideally, one would use `generic_filter` directly, but I can not get the index inside the called function).

How can I speed up this loop, potentially by parallelizing the iteration?

Comment: The single cheapest no-brainer acceleration here is with Numba, but I believe it may be possible to rewrite it with vectorized code.

Comment: My attempt with numba was that it said "The keyword argument 'parallel=True' was specified but no transformation for parallel execution was possible." but maybe I'm holding it wrong :D

Comment: @norok2 I was holding it wrong: not using parallel but `nopython=True` indeed speeds up the function.

Comment: Actually, the unique elements bit is quite tricky with NumPy code. Do you need a generator? Also, why do you add a 0 border? This is not really part of the specification you give in words. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @norok2: it would also work without the border for the implementation part. there is not necessity to do this within the function itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without the n.any(), the loop needs only 8s, so maybe there is some optimization potential as well?

This is because **Numpy function have a big overhead for very small arrays** like 2x2x2. The overhead of a Numpy function is about few microseconds while the actual `n.any()` computation should take no more than a dozen of nanoseconds on a mainstream processor. The usual solution is to **vectorize** the operation so to avoid many Numpy calls. You can use **Numba** to speed up this code and removes most of the CPython/Numpy overheads. Note that Numba does not support all function like `pad` currently so a workaround is needed. Here is the resulting code:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
np.random.seed(1234)

@nb.njit('(uint8[:,:,::1],)')
def numba_iterator(lookup):
    nx, ny, nz = lookup.shape
    for i in range(nx - 1):
        for j in range(ny - 1):
            for k in range(nz - 1):
                n = lookup[i:i + 2, j:j + 2, k:k + 2]
                if n.any():
                    yield n.ravel(), i, j, k

array = np.random.randint(0, 2, (200, 200, 200), dtype=np.uint8)

for fun in (numba_iterator, ):
    print(f"* {fun}")
    for _ in range(2):
        tic = time.time()
        lookup = np.pad(array, (1, 1), 'constant')  # Border is filled with 0
        [x for x in fun(lookup)]
        print(f" ** execution took {time.time() - tic}")
```

This is significantly times faster on my machine (but still quite slow).

> I thought about how I could make this faster, potentially by running it in parallel.

This is not possible as long as the `yield` is used since **generators are inherently sequential**.

> How can I speed up this loop

One solution could be to generate the whole output as a Numpy array in Numba so to avoid the **creation of 8 million Numpy objects** stored in a CPython list which is the main source of slowdown of the code once optimized with Numba (each call to `n.ravel` creates a new array). Note that **generators are generally slow** since they often requires a context-switch (of a kind of lightweight-thread / coroutine). The best solution in term of performance is to compute data on-the-fly in the loop.

Additionally, `n.any` and `n.ravel` can be manually rewritten in Numba so to be more efficient. Indeed, the `n` array views are very small and using 3 nested loops with a constant compile-time bound help the compiler to produce a fast code (ie. it can unroll the loops and generate only few instructions the processor can execute very efficiently).

Here is a modified improved code (that compute the padded array manually):

```py
@nb.njit('(uint8[:,:,::1],)')
def fast_compute(array):
    nx, ny, nz = array.shape

    # Padding (with zeros)

    lookup = np.zeros((nx+2, ny+2, nz+2), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                lookup[i+1, j+1, k+1] = array[i, j, k]

    # Actual computation

    size = (nx + 1) * (ny + 1) * (nz + 1)
    result = np.empty((size, 8), dtype=np.uint8)
    indices = np.empty((size, 3), dtype=np.uint32)
    cur = 0

    for i in range(nx + 1):
        for j in range(ny + 1):
            for k in range(nz + 1):
                n = lookup[i:i+2, j:j+2, k:k+2]

                # Fast manual n.any()
                found = False
                for i2 in range(2):
                    for j2 in range(2):
                        for k2 in range(2):
                            found |= n[i2, j2, k2]

                if found:
                    # Fast manual n.ravel()
                    cur2 = 0
                    for i2 in range(2):
                        for j2 in range(2):
                            for k2 in range(2):
                                result[cur, cur2] = n[i2, j2, k2]
                                cur2 += 1

                    indices[cur, 0] = i
                    indices[cur, 1] = j
                    indices[cur, 2] = k
                    cur += 1

    return result[:cur].reshape(cur,2,2,2), indices[:cur]
```

The resulting code is quite big, but this is the price to pay for high performance computing.

As pointed out by @norok2, `result[:cur]` and `indices[:cur]` are views referencing arrays. The view can be quite small compared to the allocated arrays. If this is a problem, you can return a copy (eg. `result[:cur].copy()`) so to avoid a possible memory overconsumption. In practice, it should not be a problem since the array is allocated in [**virtual memory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and only the written pages are mapped in physical memory on mainstream systems (eg. Windows & Linux). Page of virtual memory are only mapped to physical memory during the *first touch* (ie. when items are written for the first time). Modern platforms can allocate huge amount of virtual memory (eg. 131072 GiB on my mainstream x86-64 Windows, and even more on mainstream x86-64 Linux) while the physical memory is much more scarce (eg. 16 GiB on my machine). The underlying array is freed when there is no view referencing it anymore.

---

### Benchmark

```
_naive_iterator:           21.25 s
numba_iterator:             8.10 s
get_windows_and_indices:    1.35 s
fast_compute:               0.13 s
```

The last Numba function is **163 times faster** than the initial one and **10 times faster** than the vectorized Numpy implementation of @flawr.

The Numba implementation could certainly be multi-threaded, but it is not easy to do since threads need to write the output and the location of the written items (ie. `cur`) is dependent of the other threads. Moreover, it would make the code significantly more complex.

Comment: wow, okay this already speeds it up quite a bit! I tested with a larger image and I can now run the loop in ~1min instead of of minutes. I think multi-threading should be able to reduce the runtime even further, especially as I do not require the output in any particular order. Thus, overhead for synchronization should be low.

Comment: Beware of the memory leak related to returning a view `result[:cur]` / `indices[:cur]` of a larger array.

Comment: @norok2 It is not a leak but a possible memory over-consumption: the underlying array is properly freed later. I edited the answer to explained why this should not be a problem on mainstream platform and provided a solution if the problem appears (eg. if `cur` is small).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're working with numpy, you should try to avoid explicit loops. These loops are written in python and therefore usually slower than anything you can do with vectorization. That way you defer the looping to the underlying C functions that are pretty much as fast as anything can be. So I would approach your problem with something like the following. This function does roughly the same thing as your `_naive_iterator` but in a vectorized manner without any python loops:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
def get_windows_and_indices(array):
    lookup = np.pad(array, (1, 1), 'constant')  # Border is filled with 0
    nx, ny, nz = lookup.shape
    x, y, z = np.mgrid[0:nx, 0:ny, 0:nz]
    lookup = np.stack([lookup, x, y, z])
    out = sliding_window_view(lookup, (2, 2, 2), axis=(1, 2, 3)).reshape(4, -1, 2, 2, 2)
    windows = out[0, ...]
    ic = out[1, ..., 0, 0, 0]
    jc = out[2, ..., 0, 0, 0]
    kc = out[3, ..., 0, 0, 0]
    mask = windows.any(axis=(1, 2, 3))
    return windows[mask], ic[mask], jc[mask], kc[mask]
```

Of course you will also need to think abou the rest of the code a little bit differently but vectorization is really something you need to get used to if you want to (efficiently) work with numpy.
Also I'm pretty sure that even this function above is not optimal and can definitely be improved further.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to speed up your code while retaining the features is with Numba. I assume the padding to be essentially a decorating step, and I will deal with it separately at end of the answer.

Here is a cleaner implementation of the originally proposed code and the naïve Numba acceleration:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


def i_cubicles_3D_set_OP(arr, size=2):
    nx, ny, nz = arr.shape
    nx += 1 - size
    ny += 1 - size
    nz += 1 - size
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                window = arr[i:i + size, j:j + size, k:k + size]
                if window.any():
                    yield set(window.ravel()), (i, j, k)
```

```py
i_cubicles_3D_set_OP_nb = nb.njit(i_cubicles_3D_set_OP)
i_cubicles_3D_set_OP_nb.__name__ = "i_cubicles_3D_set_OP_nb"
```

If one is interested is a dimension-agnostic version of it (which comes at the cost of some speed) one could write:

```py
def i_cubicles_set_nb(arr, size=2):
    window = (size,) * arr.ndim
    window_size = size ** arr.ndim
    reduced_shape = tuple(dim - size + 1 for dim, size in zip(arr.shape, window))
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, shape=reduced_shape + window, strides=arr.strides * 2, writeable=False)
    return _i_cubicles_set_nb(view.reshape((-1, window_size)), reduced_shape)


@nb.njit
def unravel_index(x, shape):
    result = np.zeros(len(shape), dtype=np.int_)
    for i, dim in enumerate(shape[::-1], 1):
        result[-i] = x % dim
        x //= dim
    return result


@nb.njit
def not_only_zeros(seq):
    # assumes seq is not empty
    count = 0
    for x in seq:
        if x == 0:
            count += 1
            break  # because only unique values
    return len(seq) != count


@nb.njit
def _i_cubicles_set_nb(arr, shape):
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        uniques = set(x)
        if not_only_zeros(uniques):
            yield uniques, unravel_index(i, shape)
```

This introduces the important trick of generating a strided (read-only) view of the input, which can be used to simplify conceptually all the looping, at the cost of having to manually unravel the index.

This is a similar idea as the one proposed in [@flawr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72290946/5218354).

On a 50³-sized index, I get the following timings:

```py
np.random.seed(42)
n = 50
arr = np.random.randint(0, 3, (n, n, n), dtype=np.uint8)


def is_equal_i_set(a, b):
    return all(x[0] == y[0] and np.allclose(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(a, b))


funcs = i_cubicles_3d_set_OP_nb, i_cubicles_3d_set_OP, i_cubicles_set_nb
base = list(funcs[0](arr))
for func in funcs:
    res = list(func(arr))
    print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_equal_i_set(base, res)!s:>5}", end='  ')
    # %timeit -n 1 -r 1 list(func(arr))
    %timeit list(func(arr))
#  i_cubicles_3d_set_OP_nb   True  1 loop, best of 5: 130 ms per loop
#     i_cubicles_3d_set_OP   True  1 loop, best of 5: 776 ms per loop
#        i_cubicles_set_nb   True  10 loops, best of 5: 151 ms per loop
```

Indicating the use of Numba to be quite effective.

---

## No uniques

If one is willing to forego the requirement of returning only unique elements inside a cubicle, replacing them with all the elements inside the cubicles, one does gain some (but not much) speed:

```py
@nb.njit
def i_cubicles_3d_nb(arr, size=2):
    nx, ny, nz = arr.shape
    nx += 1 - size
    ny += 1 - size
    nz += 1 - size
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                window = arr[i:i + size, j:j + size, k:k + size]
                if window.any():
                    yield window.ravel(), (i, j, k)
```

```py
def i_cubicles_nb(arr, size=2):
    window = (size,) * arr.ndim
    window_size = size ** arr.ndim
    reduced_shape = tuple(dim - size + 1 for dim, size in zip(arr.shape, window))
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, shape=reduced_shape + window, strides=arr.strides * 2, writeable=False)
    return _i_cubicles_nb(view.reshape((-1, window_size)), reduced_shape)


@nb.njit
def unravel_index(x, shape):
    result = np.zeros(len(shape), dtype=np.int_)
    for i, dim in enumerate(shape[::-1], 1):
        result[-i] = x % dim
        x //= dim
    return result


@nb.njit
def any_nb(arr):
    for x in arr:
        if x:
            return True
    return False


@nb.njit
def _i_cubicles_nb(arr, shape):
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        if any_nb(x):
            yield x, unravel_index(i, shape)
```

as evidenced by the following benchmark (on the same 50³-sized input as before):

```py
def is_equal_i(a, b):
    return all(np.allclose(x[0], y[0]) and np.allclose(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(a, b))


funcs = i_cubicles_3d_nb, i_cubicles_nb
base = list(funcs[0](arr))
for func in funcs:
    res = list(func(arr))
    print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_equal_i(base, res)!s:>5}", end='  ')
    # %timeit -n 1 -r 1 list(func(arr))
    %timeit list(func(arr))
    # print()
#         i_cubicles_3d_nb   True  10 loops, best of 5: 116 ms per loop
#            i_cubicles_nb   True  10 loops, best of 5: 125 ms per loop
```

---

## No yield (and no uniques)

While it is clear that a function matching exactly the OP output can be made faster only with Numba / Cython, a number of fast approaches can be obtained by foregoing some features of the OP code.

In particular, when creating generators, a significant amount of time is spent on creating the actual objects to yield.
The same information can be returned (and most importantly allocated) all at once with substantial speed gain, especially if we skip creating the containers for computing the unique elements.

Once we are accepting to return all elements inside a cubicle instead its unique elements, it is possible to devise also NumPy-only vectorized (fast and dimension-agnostic) approaches, alongside faster Numba (3d-specific) implementations:

```py
def cubicles_np(arr, size=2):
    window = (size,) * arr.ndim
    window_size = size ** arr.ndim
    reduced_shape = tuple(dim - size + 1 for dim, size in zip(arr.shape, window))
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, shape=reduced_shape + window, strides=arr.strides * 2, writeable=False)
    mask = np.any(view, axis=tuple(range(-arr.ndim, 0)))
    return view[mask, ...], np.array(np.nonzero(mask)).transpose()
```

```py
def cubicles_tr_np(arr, size=2):
    window = (size,) * arr.ndim
    window_size = size ** arr.ndim
    reduced_shape = tuple(dim - size + 1 for dim, size in zip(arr.shape, window))
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, shape=window + reduced_shape, strides=arr.strides * 2, writeable=False)
    mask = np.any(view, axis=tuple(range(arr.ndim)))
    return (
        view[..., mask].reshape((window_size, -1)).transpose().reshape((-1, *window)),
        np.array(np.nonzero(mask)).transpose())
```

```py
def cubicles_nb(arr, size=2):
    window = (size,) * arr.ndim
    window_size = size ** arr.ndim
    reduced_shape = tuple(dim - size + 1 for dim, size in zip(arr.shape, window))
    view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, shape=reduced_shape + window, strides=arr.strides * 2, writeable=False)
    values, indexes = _cubicles_nb(view.reshape((-1, window_size)), reduced_shape, arr.ndim)
    return values.reshape((-1, *window)), indexes


@nb.njit
def any_nb(arr):
    for x in arr:
        if x:
            return True
    return False


@nb.njit
def _cubicles_nb(arr, shape, ndim):
    n, k = arr.shape
    indexes = np.empty((n, ndim), dtype=np.bool_)
    result = np.empty((n, k), dtype=arr.dtype)
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        x = arr[i]
        if any_nb(x):
            indexes[count] = unravel_index(i, shape)
            result[count] = x
            count += 1
    return result[:count].copy(), indexes[:count].copy()
```

```py
@nb.njit
def any_cubicle_3d_nb(arr, size):
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            for k in range(size):
                if arr[i, j, k]:
                    return True
    return False


@nb.njit
def cubicles_3d_nb(arr, size=2):
    nx, ny, nz = arr.shape
    nx += 1 - size
    ny += 1 - size
    nz += 1 - size
    nn = nx * ny * nz
    indexes = np.empty((nn, 3), dtype=np.bool_)
    result = np.empty((nn, size, size, size), dtype=arr.dtype)
    count = 0
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                x = arr[i:i + size, j:j + size, k:k + size]
                if any_cubicle_3d_nb(x, size):
                    result[count] = x
                    indexes[count] = i, j, k
                    count += 1
    return result[:count].copy(), indexes[:count].copy()
```

The timings, obtained again on the 50³-sized input, do indicate for the Numba-based approaches that spelling out the loops is significantly faster than looping through a view.
In fact, without explicitly looping along the dimensions, the NumPy-only approaches can be faster than the Numba accelerated one.

Note that `cubicles_3d_nb()` can be seen essentially as a cleaned-up version of [@JérômeRichard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72293158/5218354).
(Actually, the timing for JérômeRichard's `fast_compute()` on my machine and input -- with the addition of the extra `.copy()` -- seem to indicate that `cubicles_3d_nb()` is more efficient -- possibly because of the short-circuiting in the "any" code, and the lack of need to ravel the values manually).

```py
def is_equal(a, b):
    return all(np.allclose(x[0], y[0]) and np.allclose(x[1], y[1]) for x, y in zip(a, b))


funcs = cubicles_3d_nb, cubicles_nb, cubicles_np, cubicles_tr_np
base = funcs[0](arr)
for func in funcs:
    res = func(arr)
    print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_equal(base, res)!s:>5}", end='  ')
    %timeit func(arr)
#           cubicles_3d_nb   True  100 loops, best of 5: 3.82 ms per loop
#              cubicles_nb   True  10 loops, best of 5: 23 ms per loop
#              cubicles_np   True  10 loops, best of 5: 24.7 ms per loop
#           cubicles_tr_np   True  100 loops, best of 5: 16.5 ms per loop
```

---

## Notes on indexes

If one is to give the result all at once, then the indexes themselves are not particularly efficient to store the information as to where the non-zero cubicles are, unless there are few of them.
Instead, a boolean array is more memory efficient.
The indexing requires `index_size * ndim * num` (`num` being the number of non-zero cubicles, bounded to be `0 < num < prod(shape)`).
The masking requires `bool_size * prod(shape)`.
For NumPy `bool_size = 8` while `index_size = 64` (can be tweaked but typically at least 16), so: `index_size = bool_size * k`.
So the masking is more efficient as long as:

```
num < prod(shape) // (k * ndim)
```

For 3D and typical `index_size = 64`, this means that `(num / prod(shape)) < (1 / 24)`, so that indexing is efficient if non-zero cubicles are ~5% or less.

Speed-wise, using a boolean mask instead of the indexes could lead to implementations that are faster by a small but fair margin (~5 to ~20%) as long as the non-zero cubicles are not too few.

---

## Addendum: Padding

While `np.pad()` is not supported by Numba, it is quite simple to call any padding function outside of Numba.

Additionally, for some combination of inputs `np.pad()` is slower then simple assign on a sliced output:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def pad_3d_nb(arr, size=1):
    nx, ny, nz = arr.shape
    result = np.zeros((nx + 2 * size, ny + 2 * size, nz + 2 * size), dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):
            for k in range(nz):
                result[i + size, j + size, k + size] = arr[i, j, k]
    return result


def const_pad(arr, size=1, value=0):
    shape = tuple(dim + 2 * size for dim in arr.shape)
    mask = tuple(slice(size, dim + size) for dim in arr.shape)
    result = np.full(shape, value, dtype=arr.dtype)
    result[mask] = arr
    return result


np.random.seed(42)
n = 200
k = 10
arr = np.random.randint(0, 3, (n, n, n), dtype=np.uint8)

base = np.pad(arr, (k, k))
print(np.allclose(pad_3d_nb(arr, k), base))
# True
print(np.allclose(const_pad(arr, k), base))
# True
%timeit np.pad(arr, (k, k))
# 100 loops, best of 5: 3.01 ms per loop
%timeit pad_3d_nb(arr, k)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 11.5 ms per loop
%timeit const_pad(arr, k)
# 100 loops, best of 5: 2.53 ms per loop
```